# How to retry wget if specific error is found?

Tags: linux, ftp, wget

I have been trying to download a very large folder (>1Tib) with multiple files with wget, but it keeps giving me "segmentation fault" error.

```
usr/local/bin/wget -r -c -N -l inf –no-iri --user=USER --password="PASS" --no-check-certificate ftps://ftp.lab.org/GetFolder
```

Is there a way to capture that particular error (`segmentation fault`) and if found, run the above command again as with while loop until all files are downloaded in `GetFolder`?

Comment: look into lftp which has a command to download in pieces. seg faults are indicative of memory issues so you just may have failing memory on your system, or using up what you have.

Comment: Your RAM is faulty or your `wget` is buggy or corrupted (maybe because your RAM is faulty). In this situation files being written may end up distorted even without segmentation fault. Test the RAM. If it's faulty then maybe some files are already distorted/corrupted (not excluding binaries or other files important to the OS).